# JSONRpc Client over websocket C#

Tags: c#, websocket, json-rpc

I need a JSON-Rpc client to communicate over websocket to the server. In particular, I need to create an interface and use methods to send JSON requests to the server.

Does someone know how to do that?

I found the `StreamJsonRpc` library, but it works over stream and not over websocket.

Can I get the stream from websocket connection and pas it to `StreamJsonRpc`?
Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [WebSocket4Net](https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net).

You can see [there](https://lightning.bitflyer.com/docs/playgroundrealtime#jsonrpc/board_snapshot/csharp).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using WebSocket4Net;

namespace LightStreamSample
{
    class WebSocket4NetSample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var channelName = "[your websocket server channel name]";
            // note: reconnection handling needed.
            var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://[your web socket server websocket url]", sslProtocols: SslProtocols.Tls12);
            websocket.Opened += (sender, e) =>
            {
                websocket.Send(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                        new
                        {
                            method = "subscribe",
                            @params = new { channel = channelName },
                            id = 123,
                        }
                    )
                );
            };
            websocket.MessageReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(e.Message);
                if (data.id == 123)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("subscribed!");
                }
                if (data.@params != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(data.@params.channel + " " + data.@params.message);
                }
            };

            websocket.Open();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i  follow your suggestion to develop my application

Answer (score 1):

To update this post, it is now possible to pass the stream from the websocket using StreamJsonRpc.

[Github websocket sample for .NetCore](https://github.com/AArnott/StreamJsonRpc.Sample/blob/master/StreamJsonRpc.Sample.WebSocketClient/Program.cs)

```
 using (var jsonRpc = new JsonRpc(new WebSocketMessageHandler(socket)))
            {
                try
                {
                    jsonRpc.AddLocalRpcMethod("Tick", new Action<int>(tick => Console.WriteLine($"Tick {tick}!")));
                    jsonRpc.StartListening();
                    Console.WriteLine("JSON-RPC protocol over web socket established.");
                    int result = await jsonRpc.InvokeWithCancellationAsync<int>("Add", new object[] { 1, 2 }, cancellationToken);
                    Console.WriteLine($"JSON-RPC server says 1 + 2 = {result}");

                    // Request notifications from the server.
                    await jsonRpc.NotifyAsync("SendTicksAsync");

                    await jsonRpc.Completion.WithCancellation(cancellationToken);
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    // Closing is initiated by Ctrl+C on the client.
                    // Close the web socket gracefully -- before JsonRpc is disposed to avoid the socket going into an aborted state.
                    await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Client closing", CancellationToken.None);
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

The .Net Framework implemenation is similar but slightly different